# C++14 custom container supporting allocator

Tags: c++

I implemented my custom allocator and can use it like so with STL containers:

```
std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, CustomAllocator<int,100>> m1;
```

Now I want to create a custom container which supports this custom allocator. I know how to do it in C++17, using `pmr::polymorphic_allocator<byte>`. So, lets say we have some `Node` structure and a custom `slist` container class, which stores these nodes. So, to use our custom allocator, we would create a member in our class:

```
allocator_type m_allocator;
```

where allocator_type is defined like so:

```
using allocator_type = pmr::polymorphic_allocator<byte>;
```

and in `slist` methods where we need our allocator, we can use it something like:

```
//in insert method, construct new Node to store
m_allocator.construct(...);
```

And our client code would look like:

```
test_resource tr; // our custom allocator
slist<pmr::string> lst(&tr);
```

But how can I achieve the same thing in C++11/14? What should I specify in my custom container to use my `CustomAllocator`?

Comment: The `std` containers take an allocator as template parameter. Have you considered doing the same?

Comment: @Angew. Thanks! That simple idea did not cross my mind. I will try it. I just thought, that there are some rules to follow, when using custom allocator in custom container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to follow the model of the standard library and give your container a template parameter for the allocator it is to use.

When you do that, do not forget that the standard library (from C++11 onwards) requires all access to allocators to go through `std::allocator_traits` instead of accessing the allocator object's members directly (since it may not have them all). You should do likewise, to be compatible with other allocators designed for use with the standard library.

As an example of using allocator traits, consider this contrived "container":

```
template <class A>
struct StringContainer
{
  std::string *data;
  A allocator;

 StringContainer(std::string value, A allocator);
  ~StringContainer();
};
```

The following would be the *wrong* way of implementing the constructor:

```
StringContainer(std::string value, A a) : allocator(a)
{
  data = allocator.allocate(sizeof(int));
  allocator.construct(data, value);
}
```

The reason is that allocators are not required to provide the `construct` member. If they don't provide one, placement `new` is to be used. The *correct* way to implement the constructor is therefore:

```
StringContainer(std::string value, A a) : allocator(a)
{
  data = std::allocator_traits<A>::allocate(allocator, 1);
  std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(allocator, data, value);
}
```

It is `std::allocator_traits<A>::construct` which takes care of calling `construct` if `A` supports it, or placement `new` if it does not.

Likewise, the destructor should be implemented like this:

```
~StringContainer()
{
  std::allocator_traits<A>::destroy(allocator, data);
  std::allocator_traits<A>::deallocate(allocator, data, 1);
}
```

Actually, even the class is somewhat wrongly implemented. `data`'s type should be:

```
typename std::allocator_traits<A>::pointer data;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `allocator_traits` a little bit and show some teeny-weeny example of its usage? Devil is in details :)

Comment: There are tons of documentation saying what allocator_traits are and what they are used for. But I can not find any little example, that would show how to use it. I'm really new to this and do not know how to fit it all together in a context of some real example.

Comment: That is really awesome! In fact it is the only one example in the whole Web!)